# Disabling the debugging tab in the iOS simulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator

I am developing an iOS app using react native and every time I start the simulator using:

`react-native run-ios`

I keep getting this debugging tab and I am not able to disable:
[image]

any idea about how to disable it ?

Comment: The steps are the same regardless if you use Expo or not. The options will just look different.

Comment: You are right, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If on Mac `CMD + D` and choose `Hide Inspector`.

Comment: yep just saw that with Expo and its the same anyway, thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but for some reason I can't get the menu to open with cmd + d. It used to work. Can't figure out how to toggle or access this menu from the file menu. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the Hide Inspector option has been replaced with Toggle Element Inspector.

Comment: Thank you! This is defs the preferred method